# YUI Button initiates Postback Twice

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, yui

I'm using ASP.NET 2.0 under VS 2005.

`Page_Load` is getting called twice for my `.aspx` pages. `AutoEventWireup` is set to `true`, but even if I set it to false and manually add the `EventHandler`, it still gets fired twice.

```
// also set AutoEventWireup to false
public _Default() {
    this.Load += new EventHander(this.Page_Load);
}
// oops -- fired twice
```

In the `Default.aspx` page, after the user enters their username & password, I do a redirect to another page, but it seems to redirect back to the `Default.aspx` page.

I don't have any `<img>` tags without a `src`. The tags that have a `RunAt="server"` attribute are `<asp:PlaceHolder>`.

For everything else, I use YUI CSS and JavaScript. I don't have any `<ASP:>` controls.

What am I missing?

#### Update

I'm using the Button widget from the YUI library. If you specify "submit" in both Javascript and in the HTML code for a button, then when you submit, that JavaScript event gets generated twice.

This was a pain to figure out: I started commenting out bits and pieces of JavaScript and CSS (especially the includes), until the event fired only once.

Comment: Are you sure it's being called twice in the same request context?

Comment: yep -- after a redirect the control goes back to Page_Load. then when I see that it has a valid cookie, i do the same redirect (to the same page), and only then it ends up going there

Comment: Why not just put submit="false"; at the tail end of the button widget?

Comment: I meant `onclick='javascript:return false();'` but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm using the YUI framework. And I'm using the Button widget. If you specify "submit" in both Javascript and in the HTML code for a button, then when you submit, that Javascript event gets generated twice. Just remove one of the submits.

This was a pain to figure out: just start commenting out bits and pieces of Javascript and CSS (especially the includes), until the event fires only once. That way you can see what is causing the Page_Load to get fired twice.

Answer (score 5):

A redirect is a postback in ASP.NET.  If you trigger an event(enter user name and click, 1 postback), redirect to the same page(2nd postback).  Am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: Then it is acting exactly how it should.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. The redirect is to a different page. But after the redirect, in comes back to the same page and doesn't go to the other page.

Answer (score 0):

Are you by any chance using this.PreviousPage in the redirected Page ?